# Why Crashlytics create two bugs for same problem ? (Android 8 vs 7 and below)

Tags: android, firebase, crash, crashlytics, google-fabric

For the same problem, Crashlytics in Fabric or Firebase create two bugs, one is only for Android 8 and the other for Android 7 and below.

The stacktrace is pretty the same except line number.

Is that a normal behavior ?

[image: Two lines for same bug]

[image]

[image]

Is that because the stacktrace has errors on different line numbers between versions ?

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Can you share links to the issues?

Comment: I've add some screenshots @MikeBonnell

Comment: Thanks, I think we will need to the actual traces, can you post images of both of those?